# Can I write into table after calling LOCK TABLES tb1 READ?

Tags: mysql, locking, myisam

Can I call update/insert into table(tb1) after calling: `LOCK TABLES tb1 READ`?

I've read the MySQL manual which says about read lock:

> The session that holds the lock can read the table (but not write it).

I'm looking for a lock which allows me to READ/WRITE a table but allowing others only READ access.

How to do it?

Mine is MyISAM database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it in MySQL. The best way is to use [`WRITE` lock](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) but then all other sessions will have to wait for ability to read from table.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to read these first :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/locking-issues.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)

Read also about lock escalations.
I had issues with earlier versions(4.x) of mysql where I couldn't update the same 
table where I was reading from.